# Android emty cursor when query single row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

The cursor is empty only when query single row from the database. When the query match all the table, cursor returns the right information. The additional arguments that are provided when query single row from the tables are "selection" and "selectionArgs" and they are all correct. The problem should lie in the last segment of the Uri, but trying different ways of getting the last segment from the Uri (always correct value) and adding him to selectionArgs[] still doesn't change anything, the cursor is empty.

Where should be the error?

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match){
        case LIST:
            cursor = db.query(
                    ListEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);
            break;
        case LIST_ENTRY_ID:
            selection = ListEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = db.query(
                    ListEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    if (cursor == null){
        return null;
    } else {
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: Odds on there is no row that meets the WHERE clause (i.e. no row that meets the selection/selection args). What does `String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))` resolve to?

Comment: btw if you use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter you will save a lot of problems when using cursors in your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Change `if (cursor == null){
        return null;
    } else {
        return cursor;
    }` to `if (cursor,getCount() < 1){
        return null;
    } else {
        return cursor;
    }` and see what happens.

Comment: That's how AUTOINCREMENT is meant to work. [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). You'd have a better chance of getting increments by 1 by not coding AUTOINCREMENT and just coding INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. However it is not at all wise to assume that an id will be anything, rather you should get the id, if you are going to store it elsewhere, from the id column (or as the return from the insert).

Comment: so thats why i told you to use that [CursorRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b), it has `getItemId` method that can be used in forming the final `Uri`

Comment: @pskink - Hello pskink, I fixed the NPE in MainActivity 181 by deleting the row inside "mAdapter.swapCursor(null);" like you did in your test code from the provided gist. Was it the proper way and if yes why we do nothing in onLoaderReset()? I proceeded forward with my app but the lack of knowledge still bodders me. Thank you for the cooperation!

Comment: see [loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) and ^F `onLoaderReset` - so your NPE is inside `swapCursor` method - just debug it step-by-step